# Django tutorial NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

I'm going through the Django tutorial. I use Django 1.6 and Python 2.7 Anaconda. I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV3dT.jpg

Below the text captured is

```
Error in template C:\Users\bg\webD\oliverk\polls\templates\polls\detail.html, 
error at line 5
```

My application's detail.html:

```
<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

This is the site's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

This is my applicatin's urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    )
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from polls.models import Poll
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,})
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll':poll})

def results(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the results of poll %s." % poll_id)

def vote(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the vote of poll %s." % poll_id)
```

Comment: It looks like you skipped the edit in [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names) of the tutorial.

Comment: Aha, I did indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you did not defined the `polls` namespace in your site's `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```